# Startup sound is gone - how do I get it back?

Tags: macos, audio, mac-mini, big-sur, startup

I've seen many questions regarding the startup sound being BACK. I have a different experience.

I have a Mac Mini (Late 2014) and it always DID have a startup sound (right after pressing the power button). Unfortunately that sound is gone since I updated to Big Sur.

I checked System Preferences -> Sound. But the checkbox for "play sound on startup" is checked. I even tried unchecking and rechecking it. But to no avail. Sound works fine for other things so it's not the speaker being broken.

So how do I get the sound back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's back after the latest OS update (April 2021).

So if you're looking for a solution for this problem, perhaps update to the latest version.

Comment: There hasn't been an OS release this month, has there?

Comment: @benwiggy You appear to be right. So perhaps when I asked the question I had not updated to the latest version, and only when I updated now, it updated to it (though it's from March).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command on the Terminal

```
sudo nvram StartupMute=%00
```

Comment: Tried it. Didn't work.